# ошибка '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' в 27 строке

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pyperclip
import keyboard

a = input("флудилка 1.0 от beatneek\nвводи сообщение\n")

s = input("вводи задержку между отправкой сообщений\n")

d = input("вводи количество сообщений\n")

i = 0

print("на счет 3")
time.sleep(2)
print("1")
time.sleep(1)
print("2")
time.sleep(1)
print("3")

def spam():
    pyperclip.copy(a)
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + v')
    pyautogui.press("enter")

while int(i) < d:
    spam()
    i + 1
    time.sleep(s)
```

Comment: `i` у вас как-раз уже целое, а вот `d` строка, поэтому наоборот `while i < int(d):` И флудить - нехорошо. Лучше займитесь чем-нибудь конструктивным.

Comment: `i += 1` ещё, у вас обратно в переменную результат инкремента не записывается

Comment: ничего себе, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Тип переменной `d` является `str` и логический оператор `>` не сработает на него. Попробуй:

```py
d = int(input("вводи количество сообщений\n"))
```